# IF cell range has text, match to column A, return Y/N

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

**Program:**  Excel 2010
**User level:**  Medium

Hi there,

I have 6 columns and I need to return a `TRUE` `(Y)` or a `FALSE` `("")` value if the text matches in the following:

The name in `G6` matches the name anywhere in `A6:A35`, then return `"Y"`, `else " "`
(Or to save a step, if the text in `G6:H6`)

I have tried:

```
=IF(G6=A$6:A$35,"","Y") &   
=IF(G6=A$6:A$35,"Y","")
```

however I either get the reverse of what I need (Y in no fields) OR I get an `NA` error.

```
=IF(A$6:A$35=G7,"Y","")
```

matches only blank cells in all columns listed.

**I would prefer to avoid `VLOOKUP`.**

I want the resulting table to look like:

```
|  A  |   G   |  H |  K  |  
--------------------------
|Nigel|       |    |     |
|Peter| Nigel |    |  Y  |
|Sally|       |    |     |
|Enid | Peter |    |  Y  |  



|  A  |   G   |  H    |  K  |
-----------------------------
|Nigel|       | Sally |  Y  |
|Peter| Nigel |       |  Y  |
|Sally|       |       |     |
|Enid |       | Nigel |  Y  |
```

Basically I'm building a relationship builder and I need to know if anyone is related.

`A = Child`
`G = Parent 1`
`H = Parent 2`

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `MATCH`:

```
=IF(IFERROR(MATCH(G6,$A$6:$A$35,0),0)+IFERROR(MATCH(H6,$A$6:$A$35,0),0)=0,"","Y")
```

Two matches in a single `IF`.

If the first match returns an error, it gets converted to `0`. Same for the next. If both are 0, then that means there're no matches; hence `""`.

Otherwise, if any of the two matches return a number, then return `Y`.

---

Thinking about it a bit more, I believe you can use `COUNTIF` with a shorter formula:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$6:$A$35,G6)+COUNTIF($A$6:$A$35,H6)=0,"","Y")
```

And on the same line of thinking, to add conditional formatting, I would use three rules, one for each column and all similar.

On range A6:A35, I would use:

```
=COUNTIF($G$6:$G$35,A6)+COUNTIF($H$6:$H$25,A6)>0
```

On column G6:G35:

```
=COUNTIF($A$6:$A$35,G6)>0
```

On column H6:H35:

```
=COUNTIF($A$6:$A$35,H6)>0
```

Note that I'm not relying on `Y` because in the second option you chose, there can be no `Y` next to a cell to be highlighted.

Comment: brilliant work, thanks very much, works perfectly.  No VLOOKUP which is exactly what I wanted!!  Extending that, is there a way to conditionally format from this?  If cell = Y, then format then conditional format the name cells?  (A, G&H fill blue).  Not a gamebreaker, but if I can use that formula that would be great :)

Comment: @MrsAdmin Do you mean like 1, 2 or 3, in [this picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/5B0Zp.png)? Or something else?

Comment: Yes, exactly like that :)

Comment: @MrsAdmin Like number 1?

Comment: #2 I would prefer, I only want just the related names filled, I have other custom formatting so I don't need it full like #1, ty :)

Comment: @MrsAdmin I'll be gone for a few hours (3-4) and I don't have any more time right now. Will give you the how to then, ok?

Comment: it's midnight here (AU) so I'm heading off anyway, thank you for your time & patience.  Have a good day/night.

Comment: @MrsAdmin Ok, added a part for the conditional formatting in my answer.

Comment: Thank you, that is brilliant :)  I've only just now had a chance to sit down and setup my book.  Looks great, really happy.  Have a fab day!!!